# How to configure lazily a Gradle task?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to configure the following custom task:

```
task antecedeRelease(type: AntecedeReleaseTask) {
  antecedeWithVersion = project.'antecede-with-version'
  antecedeToVersion = project.'antecede-to-version'
}
```

The problem is that the properties `antecede-with-version` and `antecede-to-version` are to be set through the command line with a `-P` option. If they're not set and `antecedeRelease` isn't being called, that shouldn't be a cause for an error:

```
$ ./gradlew tasks
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ...
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'antecede-with-version' on project ...
```

I could conditionally define the `antecedeRelease` task such that it's defined only if those properties are defined but I'd like to keep the `build.gradle` file as clean as possible.

Comment: How about `doLast` or `afterEvaluate` ?

Comment: Do you need this task to run during configuration?

Comment: `doLast` happens during the execution phase. The build needs to access the properties during the configuration phase or the task needs to perform the task's configuration just prior to its execution.

Comment: sounds like you need `doFirst` then.

Comment: `doFirst` works. If you convert your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the `antecedeRelease` task to run "lazily" as-in, at the end of the configuration phase, or at the beginning of the execution phase, your best bet is to use `doFirst`

```
task antecedeRelease(type: AntecedeReleaseTask) {
  doFirst {
    antecedeWithVersion = project.'antecede-with-version'
    antecedeToVersion = project.'antecede-to-version'
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the only caveat here might be that those properties may be required at task configuration time.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to use Groovy's elvis operator like so:

```
task antecedeRelease(type: AntecedeReleaseTask) {
  antecedeWithVersion = project.ext.get('antecede-with-version') ?: 'unused'
  antecedeToVersion = project.ext.get('antecede-with-version') ?: 'unused'
}
```

If this fails still, you can consider `project.ext.has('property')` when setting the value.